# Can I say "utilize somebody"?

Tags: meaning

> Recommendation of the qualified personnel and device to be utilized to
>   perform the activity.

In the example above, I'm not sure if the bold part means:

(qualified personnel to be utilized to perform the activity) and (device to be utilized to perform the activity)

or

(qualified personnel) and (device to be utilized to perform the activity).

Which meaning is correct? Can the verb "utilize" be used for a person? In a dictionary, it's used with something, not somebody.

Comment: Perhaps it means "Recommendation by qualified personnel, and the device to be utilized to perform the activity". It's not a very well written sentence, and needs more context to be sure what it means. Note that "personnel" is a plural word.

Comment: @WeatherVane The context is to recommend the qualified personnel and device. So it's not "recommendation by". I should have included it above, but anyway.. Then can "utilize" still be used with personnel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sentence is poorly formed and it's hard to tell what or who exactly should be utilised.

I think when *you utilise a person*, you *make them do things for you* in order to gain some advantage from it. You *use* them. You *exploit* them. All these expressions are disparaging: you should be circumspect about using them.

My point is that if we can *use* somebody, we can also *utilise* somebody.

<sub>You know that I could use somebody... (Kings of Leon)</sub>

UPDATE:

I searched *"utilize her (to)"*, *"utilise him (to)"* and other variations of these in the iWeb Corpus and found a few hits that seem to be quite legitimate.

> Moreover, at times *PSG utilized him* in the central defence as well.
>
> McCrea has a special fondness for Alfred Hitchcock, *who utilized him as* an American reporter caught up in the new Nazi world of Europe.
>
> *He utilized her* to get details of where I'm working today.